# How do I convert text into an actionlink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the markup below, I want to display the Description and/or EventDate as ActionLinks. How do I make them actionable? The ActionLink defined to the right of the text works but I'd rather not see a bunch of links that say "View". It seems cleaner to just make the text or date clickable.

Thanks!

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", "Event", new { id = item.Id }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well instead of using a `DisplayFor` use `ActionLink` if you want to generate an `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Details", "Event", new { id = item.Id }, null)
```

Same stands true for the EventDate. It's just that you might need to convert it to a string which is what the ActionLink helper expects as first argument.